# Crystal Reports full outer join not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports 2008. Basically, I have 2 views in the report: 1 for transaction, and 1 for budgets. I joined them using the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM View1 AS A
FULL OUTER JOIN View2 AS B
    ON (A.[Nominal Code] = B.[Account Code] and A.[Department] = B.[Unit])
```

I need to display all budgets, reduce the expenses done so far, and also display the remaining budgets. This is working fine for budgets which have an existing transaction tied to them, however budgets which have not yet been used are not being shown in the report. In the report I am selecting using the following:

```
{Command.Unit} <> '""' and
{Command.Year} = {?Year}
```

`Unit` is in `View2`, and `Year` is in `View1`

I suspect that the selection criteria is over-writing the full outer join. Any input would be appreciated. The report displays the budgets in `View2` minus the expenses in `View1`.  If a budget has no expenses, then it is not being displayed

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: The server is MS SQL

Comment: @LukeGatt What you mean by "not working

"?

Comment: The report displays the budgets in Views 2 minus the Expenses in View 1, if a budget has no expenses it is not being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If Crystal Reports treats null as unknown you should re-write your filter conditions as

```
({Command.Unit} <> '""' or {Command.Unit} is null) and
({Command.Year} = {?Year} or {Command.Year} is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the selection criteria to a formula rather than the selection expert.